# Javascript: How can this code be reduced or improved?

Tags: javascript, html

This is some JS that I've written, how can this be reduced?
it swaps the text as in hides one div and displays the other.

```
var directorOne = document.getElementById('directorOne').addEventListener("click", changeText);
var directorOneText = document.getElementById('directorOneText');

function changeText() {
    if (directorOneText.style.display === "block") {
        directorOneText.style.display = "none";
        directorTwoText.style.display = "none";
        console.log("luke open");
    } else {
        directorOneText.style.display = "block";
        directorTwoText.style.display = "none";

    }
}

var directorTwo = document.getElementById('directorTwo').addEventListener("click", changeText2);
var directorTwoText = document.getElementById('directorTwoText');

function changeText2() {
    if (directorTwoText.style.display === "block") {
        directorTwoText.style.display = "none";
        directorOneText.style.display = "none";
        console.log("bruce open");
    } else {
        directorTwoText.style.display = "block";
        directorOneText.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a single function that is called with the elements as parameters

```js
var directorOneText = document.getElementById('directorOneText');
var directorTwoText = document.getElementById('directorTwoText');

function changeText(t1, t2) {
    t1.style.display = (t1.style.display === "block") ? "none" : "block";
    t2.style.display = "none";
}

var directorOneClickEvent = document.getElementById('directorOne').addEventListener("click", function(){ changeText(directorOneText, directorTwoText)});
var directorTwoClickEvent = document.getElementById('directorTwo').addEventListener("click", function(){ changeText(directorTwoText, directorOneText)});
```

```css
#directorOne {background:#333; padding: 20px;}
#directorTwo {background:#ddd; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<div id="directorOne">d1<textarea id="directorOneText"></textarea></div>
<div id="directorTwo">d2<textarea id="directorTwoText"></textarea></div>
```